# Integrate the fraction of a sqare-root of a trigonometrical equation

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I need to integrate this function without using numerical method

$$\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{Ax + B \cos x + C \sin x +d}}$$

where $a,b,c$ and $d$ are constant variable.

Comment: No way.$\mathstrut$

Comment: Don't even try..

Comment: Thank you for you answers.